# Python soap using soaplib (server) and suds (client)

Tags: python, soap, suds

This question is related to:
[Python SOAP server / client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751027/python-soap-server-client)

In the case of soap with python, there are recommendation to use soaplib (http://wiki.github.com/jkp/soaplib) as soap server and suds (https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) as soap client.
My target is to create soap services in python that can be consumed by several clients (java, etc).
I tried the HelloWorld example from soaplib (http://trac.optio.webfactional.com/wiki/HelloWorld).
It works well when the client is also using soaplib.

Then, I tried to use suds as client consuming the HelloWorld services and it fail.
-Why this is happening? Does soaplib server has problems to consumed by different clients?

Here the code for the server:

```
from soaplib.wsgi_soap import SimpleWSGISoapApp
from soaplib.service import soapmethod
from soaplib.serializers.primitive import String, Integer, Arraycode
class HelloWorldService(SimpleWSGISoapApp):
@soapmethod(String,Integer,_returns=Array(String))
def say_hello(self,name,times):
    results = []
    for i in range(0,times):
        results.append('Hello, %s'%name)
    return results

if __name__=='__main__':
from cherrypy.wsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer
#from cherrypy._cpwsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer
# this example uses CherryPy2.2, use cherrypy.wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer for CherryPy 3.0
server = CherryPyWSGIServer(('localhost',7789),HelloWorldService())
server.start()
```

This is the soaplib client:

```
from soaplib.client import make_service_client
from SoapServerTest_1 import HelloWorldService
client = make_service_client('http://localhost:7789/',HelloWorldService())
print client.say_hello("Dave",5)
```

Results:

```
>>> ['Hello, Dave', 'Hello, Dave', 'Hello, Dave', 'Hello, Dave', 'Hello, Dave']
```

This is the suds client:

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'http://localhost:7789/HelloWordService?wsdl'
client1 = Client(url)
client1.service.say_hello("Dave",5)
```

Results:

```
    >>> Unhandled exception while debugging...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\RTEP\Sequencing\SoapClientTest_1.py", line 10, in <module>
    client1.service.say_hello("Dave",5)
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 537, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 597, in invoke
    result = self.send(msg)
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 626, in send
    result = self.succeeded(binding, reply.message)
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 658, in succeeded
    r, p = binding.get_reply(self.method, reply)
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\suds\bindings\binding.py", line 158, in get_reply
    result = unmarshaller.process(nodes[0], resolved)
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\typed.py", line 66, in process
    return Core.process(self, content)
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\core.py", line 48, in process
    return self.append(content)
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\core.py", line 63, in append
    self.append_children(content)
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\core.py", line 140, in append_children
    cval = self.append(cont)
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\core.py", line 61, in append
    self.start(content)
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\typed.py", line 77, in start
    found = self.resolver.find(content.node)
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\suds\resolver.py", line 341, in find
    frame = Frame(result, resolved=known, ancestry=ancestry)
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\suds\resolver.py", line 473, in __init__
    resolved = type.resolve()
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\suds\xsd\sxbasic.py", line 63, in resolve
    raise TypeNotFound(qref)
TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(string, HelloWorldService.HelloWorldService, )'
```

Comment: I just tried today with current sources and got exactly the same problem as the original poster.  Adding the import statements didn't help (in fact, you can look at the original code and see the primitives imported).

Answer (score 2):

try to import primitives into your class:

```
class HelloWorldService(SimpleWSGISoapApp):
    from soaplib.serializers.primitive import String, Integer, Arraycode
    @soapmethod(String,Integer,_returns=Array(String))
```

Answer (score 1):

this bug is fixed if you get the latest sources from the trunk, see https://github.com/soaplib/soaplib/pull/12 for details