# webservices in python

Tags: python, web-services, frameworks

i want to create a webservice (SOAP & REST) in python which cab be called from iphone,
now i have install python 2.7.1 on Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS using Putty. so now i am searching for a nice and easy framework that helps me in creating webservices and web programming.

I have searched a lot but confused with the combination of framworks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992239/python-soap-using-soaplib-server-and-suds-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of

[Python soap using soaplib (server) and suds (client)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992239/python-soap-using-soaplib-server-and-suds-client)

Suds/soaplib is fine for working wit SOAP client/server side.

REST is a different story. I think you should first choose one of the many Python web-frameworks.

"Pyramid" - part of the Pylons projects - is a very strong but open-to-all-sides webframework   which could be used for both SOAP and REST-ish services.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/

Comment: well is it possible to send a json format with this soaplib and do i need other web frameworks to implement serverside webservice ?

Answer (score 0):

For REST, I am very satisfied with Flask.