# Can I write a SOAP server using python suds?

Tags: python, soap, suds, zsi

I started using [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) for soap clients and will never touch [ZSI](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/zsi.html) again.

I know suds is meant for the client side, but I would love to use it to make also the server site, in order to get rid of ZSI.

How could I use suds to parse soap requests instead of responses?

[updates]

- If you want to expose some interface using SOAP, the best option
  seems to be [rpclib](https://github.com/arskom/rpclib#readme). Flask-enterprise looks promising. Both will produce a
  WSDL from Python code.
- If instead you need to write a Python SOAP webservice adhering to a WSDL produced 
  by a third part, nothing so far beats ZSI.

Comment: Can you explain why you are so eager to ditch ZSI? I am thinking of creating a system based on it, and I think that knowing your rationale will help me make a better choice.

Comment: Ha, I can think of a sentence like your `...never touch...` sentence that reads as with "suds" replaced with "REST" and "ZSI" replaced with "SOAP".

Answer (score 7):

To write a SOAP server in Python, you can use the micro web framework - Flask, with it's plugin - Flask-enterprise

http://massive.immersedcode.org/2011/staging/projects/default/python/flask-enterprise/

There is also a similar question here in stackoverflow:

[Python soap using soaplib (server) and suds (client)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992239/python-soap-using-soaplib-server-and-suds-client)

They use soaplib for providing SOAP service, as you can find the document here http://soaplib.github.com/soaplib/2_0/pages/helloworld.html

Comment: In Flask-Enterprise is there any way to set maximum and minimum number of elements on SOAP Arrays - or for setting if a Complex element property is mandatory or optional?

Comment: My enthusiasm over Flask-Enterprise faded pretty quicky. Seems like there is no support for setting minimum and maximum number of occurrences in complex types.

Answer (score 3):

If you decided to use Flask - try new [flask-spyne](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Spyne) extension.

[flask-enterprise](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Enterprise) mentioned above is a wrapper on top of discontinued [soaplib](http://soaplib.github.io/soaplib/2_0/), while [flask-spyne](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Spyne) is a wrapper on top of [spyne](http://spyne.io) - successor of [soaplib](http://soaplib.github.io/soaplib/2_0/).